# Fading Effect in Veins 4.4 demo example

Tags: veins

I wanted to know whether fading effect is already included in the example scenario of veins 4.4?If not how to include different fading models in the simulation ??

Answer (score 0):

Fading models in the simulation are instantiated from a list in an XML file, for example https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/examples/veins/config.xml - if you want to use additional or alternative models, you can find some more in https://github.com/sommer/veins/tree/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/analogueModel